# Thicker Border Around WinForm (FixedSingle) - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I'm quite new to .NET and Visual Studio, and have taken over a project from somebody else (attached an image below).

On the main form, I'm trying to increase border thickness and/or colour. However from Googling I can only really find ways to increase border thickness for panels, or when `FormBorderStyle` is set to `None`. A lot of answers also seem to relate to C#.

At the moment the `FormBorderStyle` for the form is set to `FixedSingle`

I'm just wondering, in VB.NET, if there is a way to alter the outer border's thickness, or change attributes associated with the `FixedSingle` style?

[image]

Comment: This misses the point of winforms. Winforms uses the standard controls, in order to get consistent and familiar layouts and design language across many programs. This helps makes ALL programs more usable. When you make tweaks like this, you step outside of that design language. Your app feels less familiar, and is therefore less user-friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this, if you're adamant about it, is to override the `OnPaint` event of the form.

Rather than recreate a pretty standard procedure here, here's a link to the [Microsoft Overriding the OnPaint Event documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/overriding-the-onpaint-method) which should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look! I managed to find a workaround in the meantime. I really just wanted to add a thin white border around the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

So perhaps there is not a way to do this.

However found a workaround which gave me what I wanted. I essentially just increased the padding of the Form, and set the colour to White. Upon running the application, this looks closer to what I wanted.